# Rails 7.0 upgrade: Autoloading with Zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-on-rails-7, zeitwerk

Having trouble autoloading modules when upgrading from classic autoloader to now using zeitwerk.

Currently my modules are as follows:

```
# app/lib/configuration/test_configuration
module TestConfiguration
  ....code here
end
```

and in my *application.rb* i'm using:

```
config.paths.add 'app/lib', eager_load: true
```

Which results in the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Configuration::TestConfiguration
```

I know that this module is technically namespaced based on the file structure so after changing it to

```
module Configuration::TestConfiguration
//
end
```

I still get an error:

```
uninitialized constant Configuration
```

I also think I need to change the line in my application to be

```
config.eager_load_paths
```

and remove any *require* that are still present in there i.e:

```
require "#{Rails.root.join('app', 'lib', 'configuration', 'other_config')}"
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are finding is not really related to upgrading from classic to zeitwerk modes. It is about upgrading to Rails 7.

Rails 6.0 and 6.1 issued warnings when loading reloadable code from initializers, and Rails 7 removes that possibility. This is a logical change unrelated to the autoloader mode.

Please check [this section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization) of the upgrading guide.

Comment: I'm curious as to why my require/modules aren't available in my application.rb file then after the upgrade. 

Was using a require to load a memcache config in my application rb, and even when namespacing it correctly -- Configuration::MemcacheConfig -- and removing the require, it still isn't working. Even though this file should be technically autoloaded "by default" as it lives in the app/lib dir.

Comment: using the "to_prepare" block also results in the same error.

Comment: Is your app using Rails 7.1?

Comment: it's using 7.0.4.3

Comment: OK, memcached configuration is not something you can reload, it is set once when the application boots. Therefore, it should not be in app/lib, because that directory belongs to the autoload paths. I'd suggest moving the file to lib, and issue a regular require or require_relative.

Comment: That seemed to work. Looks like it was also causing a conflict because of the Configuration namespace as well. I THINK it's because we have a model called configuration and it was being autoloaded first, and when going to load the Configuration::MemcacheConfig, it would still throw a name error. Looks like it may have something to do with the shadow paths in zeitwerk?

Comment: Exactly! If you define a `Configuration` constant before the autoloader is setup (as the comment above suggested), then the autoloader will skip a top-level file `configuration.rb`, because that constant is managed by someone else. If you need help fine tuning this further please followup and we can continue :).

Answer (score 0):

Should be Configuration::TestConfiguration

```
# app/lib/configuration/test_configuration
module Configuration::TestConfiguration
  ....code here
end
```

Comment: You don't need `config.paths.add 'app/lib', eager_load: true`, anything under `app` that is not excluded explicitly (like views) gets into the autoload and eager load paths. So, app/services, app/queries, app/forms, app/lib, all would be added automatically by Rails.

Comment: That should work out the box. Is the application trying to access that from config/initializers by any chance?

Comment: @b-seven Isn't that what is posted up there? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @XavierNoria Yes, the app is trying to access these constants in initializers/environments. I also am just trying to access one in the `application.rb`, and still getting the `NameError`, even if I require the file. The `other_config` is being called below the require statement:

`Configuration::OtherConfig.configure` is throwing an error:

`uninitialized constant Rails::Application::Configuration::OtherConfig`

Comment: Should be `module Configuration::TestConfiguration` not `module TestConfiguration`.

Comment: This still throws an error "uninitialized constant Configuration"

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Lib::Configuration::TestConfiguration` .

Comment: No, app subdirectories represent the root namespace. app/models/user.rb should be User, and app/lib/configuration should be Configuration.